# How to evaluate the typename of a value in a conditional in visual basic?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using visual basic to write macros for excel. I have already looked up several tutorials and all of them use "If TypeOf [object] Is [typename] Then" in order to check whether the value of a cell is of a certain Type. For instance, in my code I try to evaluate whether the value in cell A1 is a string in order to move it. My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 If TypeOf Range("A1").Value Is String Then

  Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value 

 End If 

End Sub
```

However the word "String" gets highlighted and I get an error that says: Compile error: 
Expected: Object or type name

I have been stuck for quite sometime and simply cannot find or search for a way out of it. Please help.

Comment: `TypeOf` checks an object, not the value of an object. You could look at IsText or IsNumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TypeName()`:

```
If TypeName(Range("A1").Value) = "String" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there's a `Worker` class:

```
Sub F()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim w As Object

    Set w = New Worker

    MsgBox TypeName(w) '// Worker
    MsgBox VarType(w)  '// 9 = vbObject

    If TypeName(x) = "Integer" Then
    End If

    If VarType(x) = vbInteger Then
    End If

    If VarType(j) = vbLong Then
    End If

End Sub
```